# How to exclude a transitive dependency in Maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, dependencies

I have a java spring boot application A that has dependency B which is a third party jar. B in turn has dependency C. When people need upgrade C (say from v1.0 to v2.0), a common approach is that in pom.xml of A, using Maven exclusion feature to exclude C from B, then either declare C-v2.0 as a direct dependency, or add C-v2.0 to dependencyManagement section.

This approach doesn't guarantee work in all situations. An example is org.glassfish.metro:webservices-rt:2.4.3 has dependency woodstox-core:5.1.0 which contains high security vulnerabilities and need to upgrade to 6.4.0.

My project A has (direct)dependency webservices-rt:2.4.3. Applying above approach doesn't exclude woodstox-core:5.1.0 from my project. Note: the maven dependency tree doesn't show woodstox-core:5.1.0 any more, but Aqua Scan still indicates that webservices-rt has dependency woodstox-core:5.1.0.

Below is part of my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
            <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.metro</groupId>
            <artifactId>webservices-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
                    <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>
```

It seems to me that whether above approach working or not depends on how jar B is packaged. Dose anyone has knowledge to share?

Answer (score 0):

1. The much better approach is to set the desired version in `<dependencyManagement>`, i.e.

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.woodstox</groupId>
       <artifactId>woodstox-core</artifactId>
       <version>6.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies)
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then you need no exclusions at all.

2. If the dependency tree does not show it, it will not be used, unless the dependency is a fat jar. So, avoid fat jars as dependencies (if at all possible), and furthermore check if your Aqua Scan maybe does it wrong.

Comment: Thanks Fabian for the information.  webservices-rt.jar is a uber-jar and its dependencies can't be excluded.